# How to prevent overlapping animations using core.async?

Tags: animation, clojure, clojurescript, core.async

I have this loop handling animations for a character -- `set-image!` just takes a key and displays the appropriate image.

```
(defn main-animation-loop []
  (go (while true
        (set-image! :normal)
        (<! (timeout 8000))
        (set-image! :blink)
        (<! (timeout 150)))))
```

Every once in a while the character needs to do some special actions. This should be able to interrupt the main animation:

```
(defn dance! []
  (go (set-image! :look-left)
      (<! (timeout 1000))
      (set-image! :look-right)
      (<! (timeout 1000))
      (set-image! :wave)
      (<! (timeout 2000))))
```

What's a good way to pause the main animation while the dance routine is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's common in CSP style programming to pass a  **control channel to event loops** so you can, at the very least tell them when to stop. In this case if there was a control channel that went to `main-animation-loop` and you gave a copy of that to `dance!`, then dance could tell `main-animation-loop` to pause and unpause appropriatly. Or stop it then start it again (passing the same control channel in case others are using it).

I use a pattern like this to check for messages each time around the event loop:

```
(go (while (not= control-chan
                 (second (async/alts! [control-chan (async/timeout arg)])))
           (do-stuff-here))
```

This checks to see if it was the timeout or the control channel that caused the interruption.

```
(defn main-animation-loop [control-chan]
  (go (while (not= control-chan
                 (second (async/alts! [control-chan (async/timeout 150)])))
        (set-image! :normal)
        (<! (timeout 8000))
        (set-image! :blink))))

(defn dance! [control-chan]
  (go (!> control-chan :stop)
      (set-image! :look-left)
      (<! (timeout 1000))
      (set-image! :look-right)
      (<! (timeout 1000))
      (set-image! :wave)
      (<! (timeout 2000))
      (main-animation-loop control-chan)))
```

By passing the same channel to both functions, you allow them to communicate with each other. `main-animation-loop` will keep looping as long as all the messages it receives are coming from the timeout channel. As soon as it sees that one of them came from the control channel instead of the timeout, it will stop. This allows `dance!` to tell it to stop by sending any message to the control channel. In similar code I often have the main event loop check the content of the message and do more than just stop, though in this case stopping is enough because `dance!` can simply start the event loop again.

Comment: I'm somewhat at sea here. A complete code solution to the question would be very helpful - to me, at least. Thank you.

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit, though without the actual animation part I haven't run it.

Comment: Why do the docs say that `alts!!` is not to be used inside `go` blocks?

Comment: thats because the version for use in go blocks is `alts!` (with one !) I'll fix that right away.